# How are the assumptions used in the proof of Bourbaki-Alaoglu Theorem?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

I've posted this question in MSE for a while without getting any answer.

In the proof of the following theorem, where are the assumptions "Hausdoff" and "locally convex" used?

[image]

Comment: Everywhere... it's pervasive in the context. Unless you're doing radical-reverse-math, this would not be purposeful to pursue. Like asking what a symphony orchestra could do in a slightly sulfurous atmosphere at about 120 degrees F, with 60 mph winds.

Comment: Since when is this the "Bourbaki-Alaoglu theorem"???

Comment: @Igor,Rivin: I found it from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Generalization:_Bourbaki.E2.80.93Alaoglu_theorem)

Comment: @IgorRivin I have also heard *Banach-Alaoglu-Bourbaki* theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "nowhere".  The result is true without these assumptions.  It just lacks content then since without them the dual space and/or the polar of the neighbourhood can collapse to a single point.  The essence of the argument is that a pointwise limit of an equicontinuous family is continuous (linearity comes for free), a simple result which holds in a very general context.

Comment: Well, you need *some* assumption, namely that $X$ is a topological vector space (e.g., to have a linear functional is continuous if and only if it is bounded on some neighborhood of the origin).